# How do I limit the Image size to its parent container

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am doing my first WPF-Project with the MVVM-Model. I have got two views that i want to look like that:

[image: Thats what it should look like]

But sadly the images do not shrink to parent size, they stay in original size:

[image: Thats what it does look like]

Views.PictureList

```
<UserControl x:Class="BIF.Views.PictureList"
         xmlns:view="clr-namespace:BIF.Views"
         d:DesignHeight="120" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}" <!-- List<PictureViewModel> -->
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPicture, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <view:Picture DataContext="{Binding}" />
                </ListBoxItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

Views.Picture

```
<UserControl x:Class="BIF.Views.Picture"
         d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4">
        <Image Source="{Binding FilePath}"/>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

I have already tried to set height of view:Picture manualy by adding:

```
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
```

But thats not working 100% correct and I also do not want to set a fix height, because I want the PictureList to be resizeable.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: In your XAML, you don't have a `StackPanel` to bind the `ActualHeight`.

Comment: Just a note, you should not have a `ListBoxItem` in the DataTemplate (in the ItemTemplate property). You may use your `Picture` control as direct child of the DataTemplate.

Comment: No need to include the ListBoxItem in the DataTemplate.  The contents of the template are inserted within a ListBoxItem, so you're ending up with a LBI within a LBI.  Use Snoop to view this during runtime (GET SNOOP! You'll thank me.).  Also, while your requirements prevent this from working as expected (your *height* is uniform, but your *width* is not), you could use a UniformGrid and be done already :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility to "Disabled" since the "Hidden" value gives the content infinite space in the vertical direction, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

StackPanel does not limit the size of container and hence all the space is available to its child elements.

You should either set limits to your stack panel or use a better control for this case, may be a Grid.

Let me know if you need help in that.

Answer (score 0):

Two litte changes and everything works wonderfull now.

1. ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
2. No ListItem in the DataTemplate

   ```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}" <!-- List<PictureViewModel> -->
       ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
       SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPicture, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single">
       <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <!-- No ListItem here -->
               <view:Picture DataContext="{Binding}" />
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
   ```

Thank you guys!